# How can I make n number of <li> fit <ul> width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying that all the li's width to match my ul's width, here's my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/4XR5V/2/

I already saw some questions on the site and some seem to work adding

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed; /* optional */
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

But it hasn't worked. My javascript function works, I dont know why in jsfiddle it doesn't work. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float: left`.  This declaration is not necessary when elements are displayed as `table-cell`.  Floated elements shrinkwrap their contents.

Comment: Yes and I also removed height: 19px; and position: relative; in #tabs_header li { ...

Comment: That's good.  `position: relative`, by itself, is useful when you need to position something absolutely within relatively positioned element.  And, you are setting height through padding, so `height` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

use flexbox. The children will fill up available area by default.

http://jsfiddle.net/4XR5V/3/

```
#tabs_header ul {
    display: flexbox;
}

#tabs_header li {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left;` from list items:

```
#tabs_header li {
    float: left;
}
```

[fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/WFUb7/), [fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/eg4Rb/) - a working script ( by using jQuery )